# select a class (mulitple) in ID jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

So, I use Wordpress and I need to add a button who duplicate a metabox but i'm block in the Jquery function.
There is the class I want to duplicate :
[class 'inside'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVDWV.png)
. The problem is to target the specific 'inside' class of the ID. Here the code I used :

```
<script>
    $('#5d113f2038d289f391614c39043629e8').append('<a href=\"#\" id=\"test\">Add</a>');
    $('#test').click(function(){
        alert('test');
        $('.inside').clone().appendTo('#5d113f2038d289f391614c39043629e8');
    })
</script>
```

(The ID is 5d113f2038d289f391614c39043629e8) and the link 'Add' is used to duplicate these 'inside' class into the div).

I don't know if  you understand me but in conclusion : Can I select a specific class in a ID when this class is used in others ID ?

Comment: Please consider creating a working example of your problem, either using jsfiddle or Stackoverflow snippet tool

Comment: `$('#5d113f2038d289f391614c39043629e8').find('.inside')` will select all elements with the class "inside" which are children of the element with ID "5d113f2038d289f391614c39043629e8".

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

```
$('#yourID .yourClass').doStuff();
```